# Interpretation of a Code (Cases)

Tags: filtering

I have the following code, and have been asked to interpret it:

```
Cases[{1, 3.1, 2/3, x, 3 + I, "Yellow"}, _Integer | _Rational | _Real]
```

I tried to play around the code, but it seems that it only gives one answer per pattern. For instance, if replaced by:

```
    Cases[{1, 3.1, 2/3, x, 3 + I, "Yellow"}, _Real]
```

The answer will be 3.1 instead of 1!

Could you please explain the types of patterns in Mathematica?

Comment: inspect `Head /@ {1, 3.1, 2/3, x, 3 + I, "Yellow"}` and see [Real >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Real.html), [Rational >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rational.html)  and [Integer >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integer.html) in the docs.

Comment: The element 1 has the head Integer.

Comment: The two examples and the remark "one answer per pattern" suggest to me that the confusion is also with `Alternatives[]` (shorthand: `|`).

Answer (score 5):

Each of the elements in the list only has a single set catogerisation ('[Head](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html)'). As kglr says, using

> Head /@ {1, 3.1, 2/3, x, 3 + I, "Yellow"}

Will show what each of these elements are catogerised as. In this case it is {Integer, Real, Rational, Symbol, Complex, String}, respectively.

### Head:

- [Integer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer.html) is only used for... well... integers.
- [Real](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real.html) is being used for floating point numbers.
- [Rational](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rational.html) is being used for rational numbers being expressed as a
  fraction without a floating point in and that is not equivalent to an integer.
- [Symbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html) is generally speaking, things that appear in blue in the
  workbook. They start with letters and are followed by letters and numbers. Not inside of speech marks.
- [Complex](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complex.html) is any mix of real (or the subsets of real) mixed with 
  an imaginary number. Here it is reading 'I' as the imaginary unit.
- [String](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html) is any sequence in speech marks, "Like so".

***Essentially, the reason it is not working for you, is because you and Mathematica are using different definitions of real (and rational).***

Mathematica is using real to mean the set of real numbers excluding integers and numbers expressed as fractions without a floating point in, for example. Whereas I assume you are looking for the full definition of real numbers which would include these subsets. The fact that it is returning only 1 element exactly for each of those patterns is just a coincidence that that list happens to have 1 of each Head listed in it.

### Ways round it:

- Use kglr's head code above, to show all the heads for each thing in
  your list, and just manually sort them.
- If you're just interested in Real's, you can do it with a single pattern search, by inserting floating points in the integers and rationals e.g.

  > Cases[{1., 3.1, 2./3, x, 3 + I, "Yellow"}, _Rational | _Real]
- Easiest is probably what you've shown in the question though and just search for Integer or Real or Rational.

As an aside, you can also use tests such as:

> IntegerQ[3.1]

Hopefully this provides some clarity on the patterns, as requested. If there is a specific pattern condition you need, let me know and I can try to help putting something together with you if you would like. And welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange!

Comment: I don't think your "dual condition" `_Integer && _Real` works the way you imply. Consider `Cases[{1 && 3.5, 2. && 3.5, 3 && 4}, _Integer && _Real]`.  Of course, `1 && 3.5` is a sort of nonsense expression, since the arguments to `And[]` do not represent boolean expressions; but that is the sort of expression that is matched.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. I shall edit the answer to reflect this.